# way to php explode abbreviations to output full text with hyperkinks

Tags: php, explode

Current scenario:

Table 'topic' may contain row 'type' that contains abbreviations for:

- Web - W,
- Email - E,
- Phone - P

so

```
if ( isset($topic['type'])) {
echo $topic['type'];
```

could typically output

```
W P
```

My question is how to to output full text rather than abbreviations and have hyperlinks from the full text to a url, eg:

```
<a href='somesite.com/web'>Web</a> <a href='somesite.com/phone'>Phone</a>
```

What I have so far:

```
if ( isset($topic['type'])) {
    $typeArr = explode(' ',$topic['type']);
    $fulldesc = array(
        'W' => $lang['textentryW'], // textentryW equals Web
        'E' => $lang['textentryE'], // Email
        'P' => $lang['textentryP'], // Phone
    );
    foreach ($fulldesc as $abc => $name) {
        if(in_array($abc, $typeArr))
            // mental blank !!!
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
if ( isset($topic['type'])) {
$typeArr = explode(' ',$topic['type']);
$fulldesc = array(
    'W' => $lang['textentryW'], // textentryW equals Web
    'E' => $lang['textentryE'], // Email
    'P' => $lang['textentryP'], // Phone
);
foreach ($typeArr as $type) {
    if(isset($fulldesc[$type])) {
        echo "<a href=\"somesite.com/" . strtolower($fulldesc[$type]) . "\">{$fulldesc[$type]}</a>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, I am trying to compile a list where any of the array elements may or may not exist. I'm also trying capture them to a variable, something like:

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, I am trying to compile a list where any of the array elements may or may not exist. I'm also trying capture them to a variable, something like: 

$types = . $fulldesc[$type];

however I'm getting an 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING' error on this line - any clues please:

'W' => "<a href=\"http://www.somesite.com/directory/typesw.php?action=webtype\">$lang['textentryw']</a>",

Comment: You need to escape your reference to the array, either by 'W' => "<a href=\"somesite.com/directory/typesw.php?action=webtype\">" . $lang['text‌​entryw'] . "</a>", or 'W' => "<a href=\"somesite.com/directory/typesw.php?action=webtype\">{$lang['text‌​entryw']}</a>",

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest of cases you can just use:

```
 echo $fulldesc[ $topic["type"] ];
```

Make `$fulldesc` contain the final HTML/link already for extra laziness.

The `foreach` is probably redundant, you just need an `isset` or your `in_array` test if unexpected abbreviation letters migh occur:

```
if ( isset($topic['type'])) {
    $typeArr = explode(' ',$topic['type']);
    $fulldesc = array(
        'W' => $lang['textentryW'],
        'E' => $lang['textentryE'],
        'P' => "<a href='somesite.com/phone'>$lang[textentryP]</a>",
    );
    if (isset($fulldesc[ $topic["type"] ])) {
        echo $fulldesc[ $topic["type"] ];
    }
    else {
        echo "<a href='somesite.com/UNKNOWN'>$topic[type]</a>";
    }
```

Also, off-topic note: You should use plain english for the `$lang` placeholders, to someday have an easier transition to gettext. Abbreviations are nice from a programming point of view, but usually turn out harder to maintain.

Comment: Saw you posted this at roughly the same time as me. I kept the foreach loop in mine since the use of explode on the topic type indicates that there are probably several types in use there and that they want all types listed.

Comment: Nope, then I read that wrong. If it's actually a list, then the foreach is needed of course.